# Missing permissions attribute in main jar (but it exists in the jar) while running with JNLP file

Tags: java, linux, security, jar, manifest

I have the issue with missing "Permissions" attribute in jar manifest file but it is present there. I have permissions attribute in manifest file like

```
Permissions: all-permissions
```

and MANIFEST.MF is under META-INF directory in my jar file. But java still complains the attribute is missing.

I run app GUI with JNLP file on windows system and server side is on Linux (which should not matter).

Server is:

```
Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 x86_64
```

Windows is:

```
Windows server 2008 R2 Standard
64-bit
```

Java version

on server (Linux):

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

on client (Windows):

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

does anybody know what can be the issue please?

Thanks,
EagleEye

Comment: Can you share us your error message ?

Comment: Th error message says: `Your security settings have blocked an application from running due to missing a "Permissions" manifest attribute in the main jar.`. But the attribute is there but customer can't change the security level because of their policy so I need to solve this without changing the java security level. Thanks

Comment: Try the permission : `sandbox`

Comment: It doesn't work. It says the downloaded version of JNLP doesn't match with the one I try to run it with. Can it be because of the first one is downloaded fromLinux and it can have different line endings? But should not have because it was built on windows. Thanks for your help

Comment: I got a rid of error with not matching JNLP files but now it shows  original error message with missing permissions attribute. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong please? Thank you

Comment: So the solution was found. The issue was that every jar file in classpath have to be signed with the same certificate. So I unsigned all of them and signed them back again and it works now. Thanks all for their effort.